# How to auto-play the ConcatenatingMediaSources in Exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I need to auto-play the ConcatenatingMediaSources one by one in Exo-player.

My ConcatenatingMediaSource code:

```
MediaSource movieMediaSource = MyExoPlayer.getMediaSourceFromUrl(StreamPlayerActivity.this, mLiveURL);
long oneMinute =  1000 * 1000 * 60 ;
ClippingMediaSource videoSource1 = new ClippingMediaSource(movieMediaSource, 0,  oneMinute,false);
ClippingMediaSource videoSource2 = new ClippingMediaSource(movieMediaSource,  oneMinute, 2 * oneMinute,false);
ClippingMediaSource videoSource3 = new ClippingMediaSource(movieMediaSource, 2 * oneMinute, 10 * oneMinute,false);

MediaSource adVideoSource1 = MyExoPlayer.getMediaSourceFromUrl(StreamPlayerActivity.this, mPromoVideoURL1);
MediaSource adVideoSource2 = MyExoPlayer.getMediaSourceFromUrl(StreamPlayerActivity.this, mPromoVideoURL2);
ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatingMediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(videoSource1, adVideoSource1, videoSource2, adVideoSource2, videoSource3);
```

My player prepare:

```
mExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource, false, false);
```

What I am currently using following code in     onPlayerStateChanged():

```
if (playWhenReady && (playbackState == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED)) 
{
mExoPlayer.seekToDefaultPosition(mTrack);
mTrack++;
}
```

I just seek the track position.

This is manual seeking. But I want to auto-play one after another.

I don't its possible to auto-play option Exoplayer. Anyone help me out

Comment: Don't do anything in onPlayerStateChanged(). ExoPlayer plays the next item in the concatenatingMediaSource automatically.

Comment: @androidlab it not automatically playing for me. can you share some samples pls.. I think my mExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource, false, false) this one wrong??

Comment: Yes, player.prepare(concatenatingMediaSource). This should work

Comment: @androidlab please post your comment as answer. issue fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use,  player.prepare(concatenatingMediaSource). This should work.